# Redirect all url to the https with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want redirect all bellow links to the https:// medomain.com

`http:// medomain.com,
medomain .com,
http:// www.medomain.com, 
https:// www.medomain.com,
www. medomain.com`

Redirect all to the https:// medomain.com

Can i help me?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do all this in a single rule, use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://medomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 2):

Apache doesn't recommend using mod_rewrite to do this.  The recommend using Redirect.  See:

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL